# fetch year, month, day from string PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, datetime, parsing, pyspark

I need to fetch `Year, Month, Day, Hour` from strings in the column `Time` in Spark df. I also need to save those values in separate columns. The data looks like this:

```
ID               Time
111            2020-03-23-12:40:04
112            2020-04-23-12:40:04
113            2020-05-23-12:40:04
```

The desired output is:

```
ID        Year        Month        Day
111     2020         03            23
112     2020         04            23
113     2020         05            23
```

I tried:

```
data_df.select(
    year("Time").alias('year'), 
    month("Time").alias('month'), 
    dayofmonth("Time").alias('day')
).show()
```

It returned all Null values.

Comment: What this the type of the data_df.Time column? It it a string or a timestamp?

Comment: @werner Hi, it is `StringType`.

Comment: Then this expains the Null values. You should use `to_timestamp` first to convert the string into a timestamp. The `year`, `month` etc should return the expected results

Comment: What if I want to just parse it without converting...

Comment: a udf function is needed, which is much slower than to_timestamp and datefunction

Comment: You don't need a `udf` to parse the string. You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.substr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.substr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the `Time` column is a string. You can either extract the values you want with regular expressions but that would be quite painful. The other option is to convert the string into a timestamp and then use the functions `year`, `month` etc.

Also, your timestamp is not in a standard format, so you need to specify it.

```py
data = [(111, '2020-03-23-12:40:04'),
        (112, '2020-04-23-12:40:04'),
        (113, '2020-05-23-12:40:04')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['ID', 'Time'])

df\
    .withColumn('t', F.to_timestamp('Time', 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss'))\
    .select('ID',
            F.year('t').alias('year'),
            F.month('t').alias('month'),
            F.dayofmonth('t').alias('day'),
            F.hour('t').alias('hour')
    ).show()
```

which yields:

```
+---+----+-----+---+----+
| ID|year|month|day|hour|
+---+----+-----+---+----+
|111|2020|    3| 23|  12|
|112|2020|    4| 23|  12|
|113|2020|    5| 23|  12|
+---+----+-----+---+----+
```